# sudo apt-get (something) is not working

Tags: apt, xubuntu, dependencies

when I try to download something, I use

```
 sudo apt-get install/upgrade (package)
```

However, this gives me error messages:

```
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
google-chrome-stable : Depends: libpango1.0-0 (>= 1.14.0) but it is not installed
                       Depends: libappindicator1 but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

So, I tried using `-f`.

```
sudo apt-get -f install (package)
```

and there is still an error message.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
0ad : Depends: 0ad-data (>= 0.0.20) but it is not going to be nstalled
      Depends: 0ad-data (<= 0.0.20-1) but it is not going to be installed
      Depends: 0ad-data-common (>= 0.0.20) but it is not going to be installed
      Depends: 0ad-data-common (<= 0.0.20-1) but it is not going to be installed
      Depends: libenet7 but it is not going to be installed
      Depends: libgloox13v5 but it is not going to be installed
      Depends: libnvtt2 but it is not going to be installed
      Depends: libopenal1 (>= 1.14) but it is not going to be installed
      Depends: libsdl2-2.0-0 (>= 2.0.4) but it is not going to be installed
      Depends: libwxbase3.0-0v5 (>= 3.0.2+dfsg) but it is not going to be installed
      Depends: libwxgtk3.0-0v5 (>= 3.0.2+dfsg) but it is not going to be installed
google-chrome-stable : Depends: libpango1.0-0 (>= 1.14.0) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libappindicator1 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: did you try running `sudo apt-get -f install` ?

Comment: Yes, I have tried.

Comment: Do you have any PPAs on your system? If so, which ones?

Comment: Sorry, but how should I check for PPAs?

Comment: Have you tried just running `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` (upgrades more than just `upgrade`)? And are you sure that your package list is up-to-date (`sudo apt-get update`)?

Comment: there is still that same message. that I should try apt-get -f. But when I try it, it gives the same message again.

Comment: You need to omit the <package> argument after apt-get install -f.

Comment: then how do I install packages?

Comment: @user654662 You just use `sudo apt install <package>`. `sudo apt -f install` is meant only as a recovery/fix tool, not as a way to install things. See `man apt` and `man apt-get`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found out a solution to the problem. I had to open terminal and type in

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

There had been interruptions in the dpkg, and that solved the problem.

Answer (score 5):

Alright, this is a classic case of dependency mess-up.

First off, go to your **Software Sources** app and make sure that `main`, `universe`, and `multiverse` (optional) are all enabled.

Then, go back to your terminal and run the below command to refresh your package cache:

```
sudo apt update
```

Follow this up with these commands *exactly as they appear below* to upgrade your system and to clean up your dependency mess:

```
sudo apt -f install
sudo apt full-upgrade
sudo apt -f install
```

If this *still* doesn't work, we're going to have to resort to other tools, namely `aptitude`. As your `apt` is broken, we're going to have to manually install this. Visit [this page](https://www.apt-browse.org/search/?query=aptitude) and choose the most appropriate version of `aptitude` and download it. This is likely going to be `xenial amd64`, but check your system.

Then, run the following command to install `aptitude` on your system:

```
sudo dpkg -i <whatever you downloaded>.deb
```

Then, run:

```
sudo aptitude -f
```

Aptitude's dependency resolution/fixing system is *slightly* more complicated than Apt's, and as such is a lot more likely to fix any problems you may be encountering.

Comment: In Ubuntu 22_04 LTS, `apt show` works but `apt-get show` not. Maybe they changed to only use `apt`.

Answer (score -1):

`sudo apt-get install/upgrade (package)` is not a legal command.  You would install a new package by typing something like:

```
sudo apt-get install vlc #Where vlc is the name of the pkg you want to install
```

You would do an upgrade by typing:

```
sudo apt-get update # updates the repositoty packages
sudo apt-get upgrade vlc # upgrades the VLC package to the latest version.
```

In your upgrade example you posted a list of missing dependencies.  The easiest way to resolve this is to uninstall the package (in your example google-chrome-stable) and reinstall it.  It was previously installed incorrectly, apparently.

You can also resolve dependency issues piecemeal by typing:

```
sudo apt-get install libpango1*
sudo apt-get install libappindicator1*
etc.
```

I'd recommend reading the apt-get man page:

```
man apt
man apt-get
```

For most common packages you are better off using the "Ubuntu Software" feature to install and upgrade packages such as chrome.  This will ensure that all dependencies are installed along with the desired package.

Comment: When apt is broken (or dpkg has been interrupted) there's no point in trying to install anything else using... APT.] Please read the other answers in order to understand the problem and the solutions.